# LINQ Query to Convert numeric to datetime in where clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, repository-pattern

I have a field with datatype **numeric** and I have stored **hour** values in it. Now I want to subtract the hours of a DateTime field with the numeric field and compare it with DateTime.Now() in a where clause of LINQ query. i'm using this logic `private List GetInterviewExamSlots(int programPreferenceId, string lookuptype)
{
var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

```
        var schedules = uow.RepositoryAsync<CoC_Schedule_Entry>()
            .Queryable()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Start_Datetime)
            .Where(x => x.Capacity != null &&
            x.Capacity != 0  &&
            (x.Start_Datetime).AddHours((double)- x.Event_Registration_Deadline) > currentDateTime &&
            x.Fully_Booked_Flag != Constants.YesFlag &&
            x.CoC_Schedule_Entry_Type.Schedule_Entry_Type_Code.Equals(lookuptype) &&
            x.CoC_Lookup3.Hidden_Value.Equals(LookupCodes.OpenHiddenValue) 
            && (x.Program_Preference_ID == programPreferenceId
            ||
            x.Program_Preference_ID == null))
            .Select(x => new ............`
```

but it throws an exception LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '.AddHours' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: maybe you can provide a [mcve]

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 0):

Not everything, that can be expressed in C# can be translated to the store's language. What this is, depends on the specific store and the `LINQ` provider (like e. g. entity framework for sqlserver). In your case the provider can't translate the `AddHours` function call.

To get past this you can

1. remove the method call from your query, convert the result to something that can be queried via `Linq2Objects` (e. g. by adding `.ToList()` to convert your (intermediate) result to a `List<...>`) and then query it again. Now that nothing needs to be translated, `AddHours` (and any other function call) will work.
   Depending on your data this might consume many local resources.

```cs
var preSelectedSchedules = uow.RepositoryAsync<CoC_Schedule_Entry>()
    .Queryable()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Start_Datetime)
    .Where(x => x.Capacity != 0  
        && x.Fully_Booked_Flag != Constants.YesFlag
        && x.CoC_Schedule_Entry_Type.Schedule_Entry_Type_Code.Equals(lookuptype)
        && x.CoC_Lookup3.Hidden_Value.Equals(LookupCodes.OpenHiddenValue)
        && (x.Program_Preference_ID == programPreferenceId
            || x.Program_Preference_ID == null))
    .ToList();

var schedules = preSelectedSchedules
    .Where(x => x.Start_Datetime.AddHours(-x.Event_Registration_Deadline) > currentDateTime)
    .Select(...);
```

2. provide a query in the store's language (like a view if we're talking about sql) which returns the desired data and you use this a the data source of your query.

If you have very few different values for `x.Event_Registration_Deadline`, you can also try another approach:

- select all distinct values for `x.Event_Registration_Deadline`
- for each value calculate `var theshold = currentDateTime.AddHours(<value>);`
- perform the query with `.Where(x => x.Start_Datetime > threshold)`

Comment: i want to resolve this problem in a more optimized way, I can't send two requests to the DB as DB is big. it'll consume more resources as you said.

Comment: The second request doesn't go to the database. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, we made some changes to the column "Event_Registration_Deadline" (converted from numeric to int) then we used .... 
 DbFunctions.AddHours(x.Start_Datetime, - x.Event_Registration_Deadline) > currentDateTime.... and it resolved the issue with single call to the DB.